# Constructing an odd-even mergesort sorting network

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

I was searching for a non-recursive odd-even mergesort implementation and found this one:

- [Sedgewick R.](http://flylib.com/books/en/3.55.1.112/1/)

The resulting sorting network is not an odd-even-merge sort network. When one draws a diagram of the pairs, it can be seen that too many pairs are generated and others are missed.

So here is an image of a correct network with 32 inputs. A vertical line between 2 horizontal lines means compare value a[x] with a[y], if greater then swap the values in the array.

[image: odd-even-merge sort for 32 inputs] (clickable)

The code from the book translated into C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int l, int r)
{ int n = r-l+1;

  for (int p=1; p<n; p+=p)
    for (int k=p; k>0; k/=2)
      for (int j=k%p; j+k<n; j+=(k+k))
        for (int i=0; i<n-j-k; i++)
          if ((j+i)/(p+p) == (j+i+k)/(p+p))
              printf("%2i cmp %2i\n", l+j+i, l+j+i+k);
}
int main(char* argv, int args)
{ const int COUNT = 8;
  sort(0, COUNT-1);
}
```

See my [StackOverflow question](//stackoverflow.com/q/34426337) for more details and a diagram for the falsly generated network.

So I took the sorting network images for `length = 1 << i` and tried to write an algorithm that generates 2 indices `x` and `y`. These are needed to calculate the resource consumption of the sorting network in hardware.

I checked my function with `length = 2, 4, 8, 16`.

Here is my C code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int log2ceil(int a)
{ int i;
  int cmp = 1;
  for (i = 0; cmp < a; i++)
  { cmp <<= 1; }
  return i;
}

void sort(int length)
{ int G = log2ceil(length);                      // number of groups
  for (int g = 0; g < G; g++)                    // iterate groups
  { int B = 1 << (G - g - 1);                    // number of blocks
    for (int b = 0; b < B; b++)                  // iterate blocks in a group
    { for (int s = 0; s <= g; s++)               // iterate stages in a block
      { int d = 1 << (g - s);                    // compare distance
        int J = (s == 0) ? 0 : d;                // starting point
        for (int j = J; j+d < (2<<g); j += 2*d)  // iterate startpoints
        { for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)            // shift startpoints
          { int x = (b * (length / B)) + j + i;  // index 1
            int y = x + d;                       // index 2
            printf("%2i cmp %2i\n", x, y);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
int main(char* argv, int args)
{ const int COUNT = 8;
  sort(COUNT);
}
```

- Is it correct?
- Can it be improved? E.g. just 4 loops.
- It need not be very fast, because it's a hardware generation and check routine.

Comment: One code snippet has 4 loops, and one has 5 loops.  Which one are you looking for a review on specifically?  Also, I hope this is mostly just an educational exercise, as these algorithms are O(n⁴) and O(n⁵) respectively and should never be used in real world application.

Comment: The second snippet is for review. The first one is from a book and not correct. The space complexity of the algorithm is O(n * log n * log n) not O(n^5) and the time complexity is O(log n * log n). 5 for-loops are needed to linearize the recursive variant. See Wikipedia for more details and a recursive implementation. As far as I know this is the fastest sorting network. Keep in mind that hardware performs every step in parallel unless there are data dependencies. Each column in the picture shows m parallel operations per point in time.

Comment: The O(n⁵) was referring to the time complexity, which is what is typically referred to when talking about Big O and not specifying the complexity it relates to.  I'm still having a hard time believing this algorithm is O(log n * log n), but arguing such small aspects about that is somewhat irrelevant anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general your code is quite hard to comprehend due to the bracing style and the single letter variable names. A bit more spaces and more meaningful names would do quite a bit for readability (I've kept your 2-indent spacing) and also remove the need for most of the comments:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int log2ceil(int value)
{
  int i;
  int cmp = 1;
  for (i = 0; cmp < value; i++)
  {
    cmp <<= 1;
  }
  return i;
}

void sort(int length)
{
  int groups = log2ceil(length);
  for (int group = 0; group < groups; group++)
  {
    int blocks = 1 << (groups - group - 1);
    for (int block = 0; block < blocks; block++)
    {
      for (int stage = 0; stage <= group; stage++)
      {
        int distance = 1 << (group - stage);
        int startPoint = (stage == 0) ? 0 : distance;
        for (int j = startPoint; j + distance < (2 << group); j += 2 * distance)
        {
          for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++)            // shift startpoints
          {
            int x = (block * (length / blocks)) + j + i;
            int y = x + distance;
            printf("%2i cmp %2i\n", x, y);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

int main(char* argv, int args)
{
  const int COUNT = 8;
  sort(COUNT);
}
```